# Aborted jenkins pipeline job continues running later stages

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-pipeline

I'm on the latest version of Jenkins and the pipeline plugins, and I have a jenkins declarative pipeline job configured as follows:

```
pipeline { 
    agent {
        label 'default'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Prepare') {
            steps {
                dir('foo') {
                    git ...
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Temp1') {
            steps {
                sh script: 'dotnet run ...'
                echo 'Temp1'
            }
        }
        stage('Temp2') {
            steps {
                echo 'Temp2'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I abort the build during the sh script in the Temp1 stage, my expectation is that neither the rest of the Temp1 stage nor the Temp2 stage would run. However, when I abort it, it stops the sh script, then runs the rest of Temp1 stage and continues on to run the Temp2 stage as well!

Here is the log:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on ...
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Prepare)
[Pipeline] dir
Running in ...
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] git
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
...
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Temp1)
[Pipeline] sh
+ dotnet run ...
Aborted by ...
Sending interrupt signal to process
[Pipeline] echo
Temp1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Temp2)
[Pipeline] echo
Temp2
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: ABORTED
```

How do I get the build to actually abort?

Comment: This is interesting indeed. Does `dotnet run ..` give a return code > 0 if it receives an interrupt signal? Does this behavior occur in other stages of the pipeline as well or does it only happen when you interrupt the `dotnet run ..` stage?

Comment: @fishi If I do `dotnet run` locally and Ctrl+C, then `$?` is 130, so I thought that wasn't the issue. But I added an `echo $?` to the sh script and it's printing 0, so maybe the issue is the exit code after all.

Comment: Does this behavior only occur when aborting on `dotnet run ..` or does it also happen when you abort at other stages of the pipeline? If it only happens during `dotnet run ..`, then I'd bet that sth is not right with the exit code.

Comment: The only stages that run long enough for me to abort them are `dotnet run`, so I'll go find something else to test with.

Comment: You could add a `sh script: 'sleep 100'` to the pipeline and test with that.

Comment: Both sleep and a python script are aborting properly so I guess it's a problem with dotnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a dotnet issue, where it returns 0 as the exit code when killed by SIGTERM. https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/21243 was resolved several days ago but has not been released yet.

As a workaround, you can do something like this:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Environment.ExitCode = 1;

    // Do stuff

    return 0;
}
```

If `Main` completes successfully, it will return an exit code of 0. If it receives a SIGTERM, it will return the value in `Environment.ExitCode`.